# Problem while calling a javascript function using jsp

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name='frm' action="Readcsvv" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" > 
<input type="file" name="file1"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Upload File" onclick="showProgress()" method="POST">

<script>
function showProgress() {
    if(document.frm.file1.value == "")
    {
    alert('Please upload a file');
    }       
    else
    {       
    document.getElementById('progress').style.display = 'block';
    }
    }
</script>
```

In my jsp file I have the above code. If there is no file selected the `alert('Please upload a file')` is displayed successfully . But it calls the servlet program Readcsvv and goes to the next page.

After diplaying the alert box i want to program to be in same page. What should I do for that?

Comment: [Car / Carpet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java/245068#245068) you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below,

```
<form name='frm' action="Readcsvv" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" > 
<input type="file" name="file1"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Upload File" onclick="return showProgress();" method="POST">

<script>
function showProgress() {
    if(document.frm.file1.value == "")
    {
    alert('Please upload a file');
    return false;
    }       
    else
    {       
    document.getElementById('progress').style.display = 'block';
    return true;
    }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="Submit" value="Upload File" onclick="return showProgress()" method="POST">`

use this with return false

Answer (score 0):

If this were jQuery you would have to return false at the end of an onClick event handler. I would try `return false;`.

You also need to change your `onclick` attribute to be an `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` element.

Comment: So you see the alert, but once you dismiss it the page still changes?

Comment: Clicking the button and submitting the form are two different event firings. You are stopping the click but not the submission. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form name='frm' action="Readcsvv" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;">
```